# Force closing when checking if the user is already logged in

Tags: java, android

**When my application starts, it just force closes itself.**

I've checked the **logcat** and this is the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean prefs.UserSession.isUserLoggedin()' on a **null object reference**

I don't see why this is happening tho since I'm a newbie on Android Development :(

This is my **Authentication.java** (this is the first activity/class that is gonna be opened when the application starts)

```
...
import prefs.UserInfo;
import prefs.UserSession;
...

public class Authentication extends AppCompatActivity {
    private UserSession session;
    private UserInfo userInfo;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
       if(session.isUserLoggedin()){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Mainpage.class));
            finish();
        }
    ...
```

This is my **UserSession.java** (A class which handles the session)

```
...
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class UserSession {
    ....
    private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN = "isloggedin";
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context ctx;

    public UserSession(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }
    public void setLoggedin(boolean isLoggedin){
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, isLoggedin);
        editor.apply();
    }
    public boolean isUserLoggedin(){return prefs.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, false);}
}
```

Comment: `session` is `null`

Comment: I've initialized it `private UserSession session;`

Comment: [Creating Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Comment: I've think I've done that, care to upload an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using parameter as context of the activity.

```
public UserSession(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }
```

So you should initialize your user session object with context.Without context you received null object reference

```
private UserSession session=new UserSession(this);
```

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek/com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Authentication}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: did you initialized PREF_NAME?

Comment: I don't think so, how?